# Magento observer throwing error

Tags: magento

I'm attempting to subscribe to the `sales_order_place_after` observer in Magento so that I can output order data. Unfortunately, anytime I try to log output to Mage::log, print_r, or even var_dump, I receive a `User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back` error.

It's probably also important to note that I'm using one step checkout and the checkout usually hangs (confirmation email still comes through). Shortly after the hang, I receive a `PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 234881024 bytes)` error. Can't seem to track down where or what is causing the memory leak... but it this error is only spit out if I am trying to output data.

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <InfinitelyWhite_OrderEvent>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </InfinitelyWhite_OrderEvent>
    </modules>

<!-- Configure our module's behavior in the global scope -->
<global>

    <!-- Defining models -->
    <models>

        <!--
            Unique identifier in the model's node.
            By convention, we put the module's name in lowercase.
        -->
        <infinitelywhite_orderevent>

            <!--
                The path to our models directory, with directory
                separators replaced by underscores
            -->
            <class>InfinitelyWhite_OrderEvent_Model</class>

        </infinitelywhite_orderevent>

    </models>

    <events>
        <sales_order_place_after>
            <observers>
                <infinitelywhite_orderevent>
                    <class>infinitelywhite_orderevent/observer</class>
                    <method>exportNewOrder</method>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                </infinitelywhite_orderevent >
            </observers>
        </sales_order_place_after>
    </events>

</global>
```

**Observer.php**

```
class InfinitelyWhite_OrderEvent_Model_Observer
{
    /**
     * Magento passes a Varien_Event_Observer object as
     * the first parameter of dispatched events.
     */
    public function exportNewOrder(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) 
    {

        Mage::log('reached export_new_order');

        $order = $observer->getOrder();

        Mage::log($order->getData());

        return $this;

    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you share config.xml?

Comment: @RamSharma config.xml added. hopefully you can be of some assistance.

Comment: I want to see the xml of event tag of config.xml, I feel you have created for event observer

Comment: @RamSharma sorry not following. I updated my question with the contents of config.xml.

Comment: @RamSharma I tried your recommendation and had no luck. Any ideas as to whether or not this may have something to do with the fact that I'm using one step checkout? Still getting a `User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back` error.

Comment: $orderData = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
Mage::log('orderData');
Mage::log($orderData->debug());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the error was coming up because I was attempting to pull order information with `$observer->getOrder()`, when the correct approach is to use `$observer->getEvent()->getOrder()`. I was simply missing the `getEvent()`.

I'm now able to extract data like so:

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
$billing = $order->getBillingAddress();
$shipping = $order->getShippingAddress();
$customer = $order->getCustomer();
```

And then I can do something like:

`$order->getData()` or `$customer->getData()`

It's also important to note that because I switched up my observer event and I'm not using `sales_model_service_quote_submit_success` which stopped the nasty `User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back error`.

Answer (score 1):

Nick Parson .....please removed singleton

```
<type>singleton</type>
```

Comment: Still hanging and I'm receiving the `User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back` error. Is it possible this has to do with one step checkout?

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet, but what happens if you disable your observer? (Just to make sure it is the observer causing this issue).

If it is the observer, you could try replacing `$order->getData()` with `$order->debug()` and see if that helps